# MongoDB aggregate with $lookup and $count slow performance

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

The following aggregate's performance is quite slow. The joining keys in the $lookup are indexed. Are there ways I can improve its performance?

```
Model.QR.aggregate(
[
    {
      $match: {
        "owner": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id)
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        "from": "datas",
        "localField": "qrId",
        "foreignField": "qrId",
        "as": "data"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: { path: "$data" }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$data.uniqueHash"
      }
    },
    {
      $count: "total"
    }
]).exec((err, result) => {
    if(err) { } else { }
})
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an index for the owner field in QR collection? If not please add and check. And also how big are your collections?

Comment: @Arun owner is declared as { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:  'User' }, should I add index: true here? Collection datas can have tens of thousands of documents.

Comment: Yes. You need to since it's a foreign key.

Comment: Just wondering... What would the performance be like if you retrieved `"qrId"` of `"owner"` `user._id` and then used that as a direct query/count on collection `datas`.